# JUnit RemoteTestRunner NoClassDefFoundError Junit4 Eclipse 3.7.2

Tags: java, junit

I am attemping to add JUnit tests to my existing Eclipse 3.7.2 project and it seems like JUnit is not properly added to the project. I have attempting adding the JUnit jar manually. I have tried several other run configuration modifications that all result in the same error. New projects that I create also exhibit this error when I add a JUnit test.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit/runner/RemoteTestRunner
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: This is on Windows 7 BTW. I am currently downloading a new "install" of Eclipse Classic 3.7.2.

Comment: A fresh install does not fix the problem.

Comment: The classfile you can't find is part of the junit plugin, not part of junit. Are you installing Eclipse to a directory that you can write to? That is, not c:\program files\...?

Comment: @MatthewFarwell - Awesome! Post up an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you installing Eclipse to a directory to which you can't write? Windows 7 UAC can prevent certain files from being written, especially in C:\Program Files.... It's better to install Eclipse in a directory that you can write.

Comment: Odd that I have not encountered other errors before this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by a classpath issue. First ensure that you definitely have the junit.jar in your build path.

In Eclipse Indigo: Go to  “Package Explorer” right-hand click > ‘Build Path’ > ‘Configure Build Path’ > in the Libraries tab.  There you should the junit.jar.

Generally creating the test case within Eclipse adds this jar to the build path.

The same exception could also occur if you have a build path conflict. Going to Window > Show View > 'Markers' shows you the problems with the project. (In my case there was a circular reference)